# MySQL varchar column filled but not visible

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with a column ( VARCHAR(513) NOT NULL ) on a MySQL table.
During a procedure of import from a CSV file, a bunch of rows got filled with some weird stuff coming from I don't know where.
This stuff is not visible from Workbench, but if I query the DBMS with:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

I got:

```
ID | Drive | Directory        | URI          | Type ||
1  | Z:    | \Users\Data\     | \server\dati | 1    || // <-correct row
...
32 | NULL  | \Users\OtherDir\ |              | 0    ||
```

While row 1 is correct, row 32 shows a URI filled with something. Now, if I query dbms with:

```
SELECT length(URI) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 32;
```

I got 32. While, doing:

```
SELECT URI FROM MyTable WhERE ID = 32;
```

inside a MFC application, gets a string with length 0.
Inside this program I have a tool for handling this table but this cannot work because I cannot build up queries about rows with bugged URI: how can I fix this? Where this problem comes from? If you need more information please ask.
 Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT length(trim(URI)) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 32;` ? What is the result?

Comment: looks like they are white spaces try a query as `select length(trim(uri)) from MyTable WhERE ID = 32;` and what you get ?

Comment: Uhm, the result of your query is 0. I've tried this yesterday and dunno why I've not considered it as an answer. Maybe because I worked 9 hours continuosly...

Comment: so you may need to update all the rows by eliminating the white spaces.

Comment: Yep. Please, feel free to answer the question and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have white spaces in the data and which is causing the issue and when you import data from CSV its most often happen.

So to fix it you may need to run the following update statement

```
update MyTable set URI = trim(URI);
```

The above will remove the white spaces from the column.

Also while importing data from CSV its better to use the `TRIM()` for the values before inserting into the database and this will avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks. Will do for the next import.